# Is this a valid representation of real numbers?

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, real-numbers, type-theory

I am trying to find the simplest representation of real numbers on the lambda calculus. I've thought about this one, and wonder if this is valid. First, we define a real number in the range `-1.0 - 0.0` as any member of the following datatype (on Haskell for clarity):

```
data Part = Left Part | Right Part | Zero
```

With the following interpretation:

```
toFloat :: Part -> Float
toFloat x = go x 0.5 where
    go (Left x)  add = add + go x (add / 2)
    go (Right x) add = add + go x (add / 2)
    go Zero      add = 0.0
```

I believe this provides an unique isomorphism between elements of Part and Real numbers on the range `[-1.0, 1.0]`. Some examples:

```
0    = Zero
0.5  = Right Zero
0.25 = Right (Left Zero)
1.0  = Right 1.0
1/3  = a procedure that approaches its value
```

Then, a real number can be defined as a tuple `(Nat, Part)` there `Nat` is a natural number multiplier and `Part` is a real number on the range `-1.0, 1.0`. This looks much simpler than cauchy sequences. Is this structure and interpretation truly isomorphic to real numbers?

Comment: how do you define $\pi$ (or $\pi / 10$ as you wish)

Comment: As a procedure that approaches its value: `p x a = if x > PI then Right (p (x+a) (a/2)) else Left (p (x-a) (a/2)); π = p 0.0 0.5`, something like that, where `PI` is an infinite precision real number value of PI that you found by any of the many known methods.

Comment: lol.. I'm not asking how to define $\pi$ from $\pi$. let's be serious one minute : yes you can define $\mathbb{R}$ as $[0,1[ \times \mathbb{Z}$, but the problem is then defining $[0,1[$. in computer science, we consider only the definable real numbers, and there is no alternative to the (definable) Cauchy sequences of rationals. take a look at $\pi$ you'll understand why.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't get what you mean. You can use any of the many PI formulas to define it. This doesn't say anything about how you define PI, it is just a different notation. I'm asking if that is a correct notation for real numbers, basically.

Comment: no  you are asking if it is a valid representation for integers and integers divided by some power of $2$. you said nothing of the representation for rationals with unterminating fractionnal part, and irrational numbers. (how do you store them ? that's what is a representation...)

Comment: As a co-recursive data structure that approaches the true value of the real, is that wrong? Some reals like PI have infinite decimal expansions, so, pi's definition would be something like: `pi = ((λ x . x x) (λ self . (λstuff_here) self (λstuff_here)))`. I'll get something like that working as a proper Haskell program and ask those guys if my representation is isomorphic to reals or if there are some reals which can't be expressed with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not. Even if you fix the typos (right now there is no difference between Left and Right), what would be Left 1.0?

Basically, you are reinventing binary representation of real numbers, and it's well known that some numbers have two representations.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense, it is just the binary representation of real numbers, it seems. What do you mean with `Left 1.0`, though? That is a type error. Thank you! :)

Comment: So is your's `1.0 = Right 1.0`. I was referring to this, of course. So, if you say `number1_0 = Right number1_0`, then `toFloat number1_0 = 1.0` (actually, it diverges, but gets arbitrarily close to 1.0), and `toFloat (Left number1_0) = 0` in the same sense.

Comment: oh. Yes, `Left 1.0` would be 0 in that sense. Why the question, though? Was it to point that there are multiple representations of 0?